# Which touch event should e.preventDefault() be called in to cancel a "click" on a touch device?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To prevent a click from firing, you can call `e.preventDefault()` in a `click` event handler. This lets you bind an event to `mousedown`, see if something happens like the mouse moving a certain distance, and if so, prevent the click when the mouse button is released.

A click handler with `e.preventDefault()` does not seem to prevent a click on certain touch devices however. (I am testing on an iPad mini). I have also tried calling `e.preventDefault()` in the `touchend` handler, which seems to do nothing.

Calling `e.preventDefault()` in the `touchstart` blocks the page from scrolling, and is also useless because it is too early to tell if the click should be cancelled. Only `touchmove` can decide if a cancel needs to occur.

The issue is, when a user drags a draggable element which is also a link, it needs to cancel the "click" of the link on `fingerup`. This works just fine on a desktop by cancelling the click event.

Is there an equivalent event I can cancel that stops an "armed click" from going off once the user lifts their finger up?

Comment: can you show the code on jsfiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

iOS is known to not register the `click` event property. This is likely due to the fact that iOS waits a little longer to [determine how a click should be interpreted as](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html):

- the start of a pinching/zooming gesture
- two or multiple-finger panning
- the start of scrolling
- the start of double tapping
- a simple tap event (which we are trying to capture)
- the start of touch-and-hold

Therefore, you can listen to the [`tap`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) event instead, included in [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

> The jQuery Mobile tap event triggers after a quick, complete touch
>   event that occurs on a single target object. It is the gesture
>   equivalent of a standard click event that is triggered on the release
>   state of the touch gesture.

The `tap` event is not native, because it relies on conditionally listening upon `touchstart` to determine if the start and stop targets are the same: if so, jQuery Mobiel determines that it is indeed a genuine `tap` event and fires the custom, non-native event `tap`. This logic can be seen in the [original source file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js), at line 75 onwards of `./js/events/touch.js`.

An example usage is as follow:

```
$(selector).on('tap', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `Tap` must be based on some native event though, right? Isn't there a way to do the same without needing the Jquery mobile library? We have Jquery but not Jquery mobile.

Comment: It is likely that the `tap` event is not a native browser event, but interpreted, possibly conditionally so, by jQuery mobile library to ensure maximal device compatibility: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js. Basically a `tap` event is evaluated if  the start target is the same as the stop target (line 75–76). Alternatively you can use this fiddle example to manually register a tap event without including the jQ mobile library: http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/56Szw/

Comment: But if `tap` is not native, calling `preventDefault` on it wouldn't help. You would need to `preventDefault` on a native event. Calling `preventDefault` on `touchend` doesn't seem to stop a click if the finger went down on an `a` element.